# WHMCS open ticket as supporter/admin via API

Tags: php, api, whmcs

I am building an addon that will let my companies employees get an overview of their clients and for that I need the addon to be able to open support tickets as my employees.

WHMCS got a fine API that lets you open a support ticket:

```
 $command = "openticket";
 $adminuser = "admin";
 $values["clientid"] = "1";
 $values["deptid"] = "1";
 $values["subject"] = "API Ticket";
 $values["message"] = "This is a sample ticket opened by the API";
 $values["priority"] = "Low";
 $values["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize(array("8"=>"mydomain.com")));

 $results = localAPI($command,$values,$adminuser);
```

Taken from [DOCS:API:Open ticket](http://docs.whmcs.com/API%3aOpen_Ticket)

But this code opens the ticket as the client not the supporter. How can I turn it around and create it as the supporter and await answer from the client like I can do via the WHMCS interface support -> open new ticket?

Comment: I think in this context "Open" means "create". Have you looked at Get Tickets API?

Comment: Yeah I want to create/open the ticket. Get tickets API should only be useful to get existing tickets. I need to create a new one with the first message as the supporter not the client.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I contacted the WHMCS support for this issue.

They accepted that this is a bug in their system and provided a workaround for this issue.

As a workaround you can use external API instead of local API that will open the ticket as supporter.

Regards,
Dharmendra